# $f(x) = ax^5-17x^4-15x^3+153x^2-122x-b$, solve for $ a, b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The polynomial function $f(x) = ax^5-17x^4-15x^3+153x^2-122x-b$ has one of its zeroes at $x=5$ and passes through the point $ (1,-64).$

a) Find the values of $a$ and $b$

b) Determine all the factors of $f(x)$

Comment: ive tried to make two equations from f(5)=0 and f(1)=-64 and a comes out to be a decimal, i dont know where to go from there

Comment: 1->3125a-b=9285
2->a-b=-63

Comment: Now substitute $a = b - 63$ into $a$ from the first equation.

Comment: ive done substitution and cancelling out and it seems that a and b values come out to a decimal

Comment: Recompute $f(5) = 0$, just to be sure your first equation is correct. I checked the second, and you are correct on that.

Comment: i checked it again and it was the same

Comment: Yes, I rechecked too: recalculate $(3125)(b - 63) - b = 9285$

Comment: yeah i guess ill have to go with that

Comment: thanks, i think its just a problem with the question my textbook has too many mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One equation:**

- Evaluate at $f(5) = 0\quad$ (Because one of the functions zeros is at $x = 5 \implies f(5) = 0)$

**Second equation evaluate:**

- $f(1) = -64\quad$ (Because the point $(1, -64)$ lies on the line).

$\implies$ Two linear equations, two unknowns, $a, b$: from which you can solve for $a, b$

---

Once you  know $a, b$, you'll have a fully specified polynomial. You already know a factor: one of the zeros of $f(x)$ is $x = 5$ is a root $\implies (x - 5)$ is a factor.

Comment: Ask questions if you're stuck...

Comment: ive done this and when i substitute or cancel out,using the two equations, the a and b values come out to be decimals

Comment: Keep them in fraction form...I've posted what I obtained above, in a comment.

Comment: Did you obtain the same fractions I posted above: $b = \dfrac{51540}{781},\; a = \dfrac{2337}{781}$?

Comment: I'd suggest leaving it at that, and checking with your instructor as to possible typos: it might be a simple incorrect sign (-/+) before a term. Let me know if I can help anymore.

Comment: ok thanks, yea ill talk to my teacher

Answer (score 3):

Calulate $f(5)$, which is $0$.
Also caluculate $f(1)$, which is $-64$.

Now you have two linear equations with two variables $a$ and $b$.

Try to solve the equations.